# Anythingslider and Youtube API passing variable

Tags: jquery, variables, anythingslider

I'm trying to bind the Youtube API with a jQuery Anythingslider, and I'm achieving it.

Now, I need to pass the variable "**newState**" defined out of anythingslider (within "onPlayerStateChange" from Youtube API) into its callback.
This is the code, first the variable and then the anythingslider:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(newState) {
....
// other stuff not important 
....
}

jQuery.(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('#myslider').anythingSlider({
    easing : "swing",
    width  : 500,
    ............
    ............
    onSlideComplete : function(){
                      jQuery('.button').click(function(){
                      if (newState == '3') {....}
                      });
                      }
    });
});
```

This code returns me: "newState" is undefined..obviously..thanks a lot

Comment: whats the question? You have to assin a value to newState somwhere...obviously?

Comment: yes, newState is undefined into "onSlideComplete" Anythingslider callback, while before (into "onPlayerStateChange" function) is defined by default and it works..

Comment: so, the question is: "How can I define newState within the Anythingslider callback too ? " thanks again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but the latest version of AnythingSlider has a [video extension](http://proloser.github.com/AnythingSlider/video.html) that will automatically continue playing a video when the panel comes into view, and pause the video when it goes out of view. This extension currently supports HTMl5, YouTube (embed & iframe) and Vimeo (embed & iframe) with additional code on the [video wiki page](https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider/wiki/Video) to control JW Player and Flow Player (without the extension).

If you are using this extension and you need to get the status of the video, it is accessible using this external method:

```
var slider = $('#slider').data('AnythingSlider'),
    index = slider.$currentPage.find('[id^=asvideo]')[0].id.replace(/asvideo/,''),
    status = slider.video.list[index].status;
```

*Note*: The status value is a number for YouTube videos and a string ('play', 'pause' and 'finish') for Vimeo videos. HTML5 video status can be accessed directly and does not have a status variable.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments:

In onPlayerStateChange you have an argument called newState, so I'm guessing you call that function by doing something like

```
result = OnPlayerStateChange(1);
```

So newState is always defined, locally to that function.

If you want to access the same value in other functions, you need to define this variable outside all functions, in the global space, so

```
var newSate = 1
```

(maybe at the top of the js source to avoid confusion)

Hope that helps

Comment: I thought about your solution, but I don't know the value of the newState variable (var newState = 1), I must put it in a 'if' statement

Comment: every variable must start off with a a value... If you don't know the value how are you suppost to use it? your not making much sense

Comment: or just do var newState = 0; then the anythingSlider will change the value of newState?